# Running rails new with template URL fails with HTTP Error Code 406

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using Rails 5.0.0 and Ruby 2.5

The `rails new` command takes an option named `-m` that is supposed to allow you to pass a url to a template. [Reference Doc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/rails_application_templates.html)

However, when I attempt to pass a url to a very simple template file that I have up on [Github](https://github.com/jw81/Rails_Templating/blob/master/template.rb), I get a `406 Not Acceptable` HTTP Error Code.

**This is the command I'm running** ::

`rails new helloworld -m https://github.com/jw81/Rails_Templating/blob/master/template.rb`

**This is the error I get** ::

```
apply  https://github.com/jw81/Rails_Templating/blob/master/template.rb
   Traceback (most recent call last):
    27: from /usr/local/bundle/bin/rails:23:in `<main>'
    26: from /usr/local/bundle/bin/rails:23:in `load'
    25: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.0.0/exe/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    24: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    23: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    22: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/cli.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
    21: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    20: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    19: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/commands/application.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
    18: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/base.rb:466:in `start'
    17: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/group.rb:232:in `dispatch'
    16: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `invoke_all'
    15: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `map'
    14: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `each'
    13: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:133:in `block in invoke_all'
    12: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
    11: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    10: from (eval):1:in `apply_rails_template'
     9: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/generators/app_base.rb:158:in `apply_rails_template'
     8: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/thor-0.20.0/lib/thor/actions.rb:220:in `apply'
     7: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.5.0/open-uri.rb:35:in `open'
     6: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.5.0/open-uri.rb:735:in `open'
     5: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.5.0/open-uri.rb:165:in `open_uri'
     4: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.5.0/open-uri.rb:224:in `open_loop'
     3: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.5.0/open-uri.rb:224:in `catch'
     2: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.5.0/open-uri.rb:226:in `block in open_loop'
     1: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.5.0/open-uri.rb:755:in `buffer_open'
     /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.5.0/open-uri.rb:377:in `open_http': 406 Not Acceptable (OpenURI::HTTPError)
```

I can download the `template.rb` file and pass the disk location of the file into the `-m` option and it works just fine.  But passing the Github URL to `-m` doesn't work.

Has anyone else ever ran into this and can tell me if I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: I get the same error using Rails 5.1.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide a link to the raw file, not the html page that shows the file. In the case of the file in your example, that link is:

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jw81/Rails_Templating/d63247b282bef19ae5ac64504089fa83baafbcec/template.rb
```

You can get the raw link to any file on github by clicking the "Raw" button at the right side of the header.

Comment: That is exactly what the problem was!  I wasn't hitting the url for the raw view for the file.  It works perfectly now.  Haha, I feel so dumb now.  Thanks a ton!